# Customizing ExplorerBrowser from the Windows API Code Pack

Tags: winapi, windows-7, windows-explorer

Today I ran into the ExplorerBrowser from the Windows API Code Pack... This looks like a fantastic control to use as a Explorer like control in my application.. However, I am trying to modify the Commands toolbar, which is located on the top of the ExplorerBrowser control. I have noticed I have some control..I can Hide the CommandsOrganize and the CommandsView parts of the toolbar, but I really need to Hide some other controls as well..

This is what I trying to get:

I want to HIDE --> 'Organize', 'Open With','Include in Library','Burn', 'Print' etc controls
I want to show --> SHOW 'New Folder' and 'CommandsView' controls (CommandsView to modify the view - detail - small icons - etc).

Does anybody know if this is possible? If yes.. How?

I have though about creating a whole separate toolstrip or something like that, but then I don't know how to handle the 'New Folder' button..

Thanks in advance for your help!

Kind regards,
Pim